# IntelliJ inspection -- non-thrown exception

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This is a follow-up question to 1832203.  I'm making it a new question as well, because it seems that posting an answer to a question doesn't change its position on the java page and so I'm worried that it won't get seen.  Apologies if I've just stepped on some etiquette toes.

I'm an IntelliJ newbie -- started using it two days ago and I'm absolutely head-over-heels in love!  One of the things I adore is the code inspections.  However...

In one of my classes I often create exceptions without throwing them.  If I can't turn off (or downgrade) the inspection warning for this then I can see I'm going to end up ignoring inspections on at least that file (if not the entire project), which would be a real pity.

I've done a search in the inspection settings for "exception", and found nothing that relates exactly, so I turned them all off just to see, and it's still doing it (even after a rebuild...BTW when are inspections redone? at save? at rebuild? ???), so I would really like some help on how to make this one into an info/typo level -- which I can then ignore.

Using the free version, if that makes any difference

TIA to all those experienced IntelliJ warriors out there!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press Alt+Enter to show inspection popup, then press Right Arrow to see available options. You'll see there options to suppress this current instance of warning, for this class or completely turn it off.

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't know I could do this.  Silly me, I was searching in the options for "exception", didn't think to search for "throwable"!!! :(